# Как увеличить зону отображения графика

Tags: mathematica

Я строю график некоторой функции с помощью Manipulate и Plot. Например `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x ], {x, 0, 10},AspectRatio -> 0.2], {a, 1, 10}]`
Но на экране её видно довольно плохо, т.к. область отрисовки чрезвычайно мала(где-то 2 на 6 см).

Как можно увеличить этот график, чтобы он, например, на пол экрана был?

P.S.

Обнаружил опцию ImageSize, которая отлично подходит. Но если кто-то знает другие возможности, буду крайне признателен)